# Manually bind MVC model to checkbox without HTML helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, model-binding

I am building a screen from an array of ViewModel objects that contain three fields:

```
    public class StartViewModel {

        public string Id{ get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool Accept { get; set; }
    }
```

I am then trying to bind it to my view like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="StartRequests[<%: i.ToString()  %>].Name" value="<%: StartRequests.Name %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="StartRequests[<%: i.ToString()  %>].Id" value="<%: StartRequests.Id%>" />
```

I then want to bind the Accept flag to a checkbox.  I understand that the checkbox lacks a name attribute so I can't use it immediately and I understand that the Html.CheckBoxFor will generate a second hidden field that will store the value.  So here is my issue.

I do not have the ability to use javascript.  I need to configure this checkbox to effectively adjust the value in the ViewModel but I do not know how to make this happen.  How do the Html.CheckBox helper populate the hidden field that it generates? I assumed it did so with javascript.  Can someone help me understand a way to do this? I am still working through the ideas behind Model binding.

Comment: The Html Helpers do not use Javascript, except maybe for client-side validation (which is injected into the page as Javascript). Html Helpers are pure server-side code, using a string helper object to stitch together HTML elements and attributes. If you can't use Javascript, and what you are trying to do needs client-side behaviour (i.e. in the browser before your Submit), you are out of luck.

Comment: Given this, why is `Html.CheckBoxFor` out?

Answer (score 1):

For following model:

```
public class StartViewModel {

    public string Id{ get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Accept { get; set; }
}

//-> Accept = false.
```

The solution:
Change `public bool Accept { get; set; }` to `public string Accept { get; set; }`

When submit, if checkbox is checked, The "Accept" value = "on". You can detect checked value by the way.